# Popup windows for histogram with AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, chart.js

I would like to have some kind of popup window that will display a chart on the same page as where I clicked the button.
Something like this:

[image]

How would I achieve this in AngularJS? I have already set-up all the multi view files, like modules, controllers etc. I assume I only need to change HTML template for the main controller?

**UPDATE**

I have histograms loading on separate component with route `#!/histogram/:elemId`.
So in fact everything is ready in terms of creating a graph and data collection.

What I want to do is to have such popup window that displays on the same page, where the link was clicked. Something like `alert()`, but so it's not displayed by browser, but by the page, if this makes sense

You can see the code at [GitHub](https://github.com/giosal/np04-slow-control)

Comment: Well you have first learn how AngularJS works. If you have knowledge, it is really easy, how can we help you?
You need to have AngularJS configured on your page, and with a modal you can generate from the controller the data collection and the graph.

Comment: Hello, I have updated the post to make it clearer that I have already created histograms/graphs component and it is working as separate route

Comment: @Ivan-San, hello

Answer (score 0):

Well you have to create a popup modal that it's gonna be the base, I don't have full time to explain it right here but I left you a simple tutorial on YouTube youtube.com/watch?v=aqCMlI6Wq64

Make a ng-controller like:

```
<div class="chart" ng-controller="histogramController">
    <p>Stuff here</p>
</div>
```

Then the controller can you make:

```
function histogramController($scope) {
   // Chart.js functions on scope
}
```